# Issue dismissing Popover presenting another ViewController

Tags: swift, ios8, popover

I've create a Popover segue in my project and inside a button to when it's touched open another `ViewController` modally. Then inside the another `ViewController` I've a button to dismiss the actual `ViewController` and the Popover too with the following code :

```
var tmpController :UIViewController! = self.presentingViewController;

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {()->Void in
        println("done");
        tmpController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil);
    });
```

My problem is that when the actual `ViewController` is dismissed the Popover is like in FullScreen, then it resize to its original size and is dismissed after, and the resize process is animated.

What is causing this behaviour ?
How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to dismiss the popover view controller from the parent view controller using delegation/notification.

Comment: Yes I could , but what I want to know is Why this happens in this way